# SSL applying to too many domains

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I am having a problem with OpenSSL. I am on an apache server, which I am using to deal with SSL. I am only directing it to apply SSL to one domain, but it seems to be doing a blanket apply.

Comment: belongs to http://serverfault.com

Comment: It seems to be an OpenSSL problem; I don't know if I should just refuse SSL on the other domains. I would prefer something more elegant than a simple hack.

Answer (score 0):

If this a description of the problem:

http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1585.html

the answer (according to http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) is

> it is impossible to host more than one SSL virtual host on the same IP address and port